# Stooge Sort exponentially slower in Python compared to Java?

Tags: java, python, sorting, python-3.x, recursion

I've implemented stooge sort in both Python and Java, but as the input size increases, the running time in Python appears to increase exponentially compared to the Java implementation. I know that it isn't uncommon for an algorithm to run faster in Java than in Python, but surely it can't be this much slower.

Here's the Java code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stooge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[10000];
        for (int i = 10000; i > 0; i--) {
        nums[10000-i] = i;
        }
        stoogeSort(nums);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }

    public static void stoogeSort(int[] L) {
        stoogeSort(L, 0, L.length);
    }

    public static void stoogeSort(int[] L, int i, int j) {
        if (L[j-1] < L[i]) {
        int tmp = L[i];
        L[i] = L[j-1];
        L[j-1] = tmp;
        }
        if (j - i >= 3) {
            int t = (j - i) / 3;
            stoogeSort(L, i, j-t);
            stoogeSort(L, i+t, j);
            stoogeSort(L, i, j-t);
        }
    }
}
```

and the equivalent Python version:

```
def main():
    nums = [i for i in range(10000, 0, -1)]
    stoogeSort(nums)
    print(nums)

def stoogeSort(L):
    stoogeSortRec(L, 0, len(L))

def stoogeSortRec(L, i, j):
    if L[j-1] < L[i]:
        tmp = L[i]
        L[i] = L[j-1]
        L[j-1] = tmp
    if j-i >= 3:
        t = (j-i) // 3
        stoogeSortRec(L, i, j-t)
        stoogeSortRec(L, i+t, j)
        stoogeSortRec(L, i, j-t)
```

Comment: No need for a temp variable when swapping variables in Python: `L[i], L[j-1] = L[j-1], L[i]`

Comment: I'm really confused as to why you're calling the same function twice. (You call the same stoogeSortRec in the first and the last.)

Also, not really relevant to the question, but you don't need to use tmp for swaps in python. `L[i], L[j-1] = L[j-1], L[i]`

Comment: @Imagine: The repeated sorting is part of the [Stooge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) algorithm, named after the Three Stooges. Note that this algorithm is even slower than Bubble Sort.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, I'm only doing it this way to make it easier to compare the two. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: What do you mean by "exponentially"? Did you try with input and the ratio of the timings grows as `2^n` or you are just using the term randomly? However this is a classical example where a JIT makes a *huge* difference because it can optimize tons of stuff when operating on an array of ints... Try to run the python code in PyPy.

Comment: @Bakuriu I didn't check to see if it's actually 2^n, but I can tell you it's definitely growing at a rate greater than polynomial time. I'll try your suggestion though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your version is a.py.

A modified version which uses a list as stack to avoid recursion (b.py):

```
def main():
    nums = [i for i in range(5000, 0, -1)]
    stoogeSort(nums)
    print(nums)

def stoogeSort(L):
    stack = [(0, len(L))]
    while stack:
        i, j = stack.pop()

        if L[j - 1] < L[i]:
            L[i], L[j - 1] = L[j - 1], L[i]
        if j - i >= 3:
            t = (j - i) // 3
            stack.append((i, j - t))
            stack.append((i + t, j))
            stack.append((i, j - t))
```

Times:

```
$ time pypy a.py >/dev/null 
real    2m1.855s
user    2m1.300s
sys     0m0.453s


$ time pypy b.py >/dev/null
real    1m33.410s
user    1m32.810s
sys     0m0.413s
```

No even Pypy likes recursion.

I gave up on cpython (2 & 3) after 15m.

Comment: That's very useful, thank you! I'd still like to know why the recursive version is so much slower compared to Java though.

Comment: There are no interpreter/jit tricks to speedup the non-tail recursive calls so I don't know. Maybe Java is just faster for small operations (+, - //) and function calls.